# typescript , spread and object.assign

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I was just browsing through some typescript generated code and was somewhat surprised at the code for spread

**test.ts**

```
let task = { ...data };
```

**test.js**

```
let task = Object.assign({}, data);
```

I double-checked the `tsconfig.json` file and have under compilerOptions

```
"target": "es2017",
```

I thought that the spread operator was valid es6 code

So, changed the target to read

```
"target": "ESNext",
```

and my test.js now has

```
let task = { ...data };
```

I'm using typescript 2.7.2

So, basically the question boils down to why do I need EsNext instead of es2017 / es6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Object** rest/spread properties are, unlike the **Array** rest/spread properties, not included in the ES2017 spec. They are however included in the ES2018 spec.

Comment: oh, ok, I thought they were included in es6. That does answer the question though, so thanks !

Comment: If it answers the question, can you mark it as answer? ;)